# Remove files from one folder that contained in another folder

Tags: bash, shell, console

I'am trying to write simple script that will get files name from one folder and search them in another folder and remove if found them in that folder.
Got two folder like

```
/home/install/lib

/home/install/bin

/home/install/include
```

and

```
/usr/local/lib

/usr/local/bin

/usr/local/include
```

I want to remove all file's from /usr/local/lib{bin,include} that contains in /home/install/lib{bin,include}. For example having

```
/home/install/lib/test1

/usr/local/lib/test1
```

scritp will remove /usr/local/lib/test1. I tried to do it from each separate directory

/home/install/lib:ls -f -exec rm /usr/local/lib/{} \;
but nothing. Can you help me to manage with this simple script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create script `rmcomm`

```
#!/bin/bash
a="/home/install/$1"
b="/usr/local/$1"
comm -12 <(ls "$a") <(ls "$b") | while read file; do
  rm "$b/$file"
done
```

Then call this script for every pair:

```
for dir in lib bin include; do rmcomm "$dir"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple.  Remove the `echo` from the line containing `rm` to run it after you've ensured it's doing what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs[0]=lib
dirs[1]=bin
dirs[2]=include

pushd /home/install

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    for file in $(find $dir -type f)
    do
        # Remove 'echo' below once you're satisfied the correct files
        # are being removed
        echo rm /usr/local/$file
    done
done

popd
```

Comment: Thank's for replying. The main target is to do it in one line, which can be run directly from console.

Comment: It's a script.  Once you've saved it to a file and `chmod`d it `+x` it will be runnable directly from the console.